# Rails 5.1.: universal helper for passing role info to controllers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

How can I create a universal method in this role helper to pass this to multiple controllers?

```
module Common::RolesHelper

  def index_roles
    unless @roles.any? { |role| role.viewer_rolevalue? ||
                                role.editer_rolevalue? ||
                                role.creater_rolevalue? || 
                                role.deleter_rolevalue? }
    redirect_to errors_path
    end
  end

end
```

My model looks like this:

```
class Role < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user, optional: true, inverse_of: :roles
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :user
  validates :user, presence: true

  enum general: { seller: 1, buyer: 2, seller_buyer: 3}, _suffix: true
  enum dashboard: { denied: 0, viewer: 1, editer: 2, creater: 3, deleter: 4}, _suffix: true
  # more follow here...

end
```

My naive idea is that I could include this helper and then somehow define in `DashboardsController` that, for example, `rolevalue=dashboard`.

Then this particular code would work for Dashboards.

In other controllers, I would define their values and include this helper again.

Is there any option to do this?

Comment: I suggest looking into authorization gems like [pundit](https://github.com/elabs/pundit) or [cancancan](https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan) instead of building your own.

Comment: Just use [Pundit](https://github.com/elabs/pundit). This is a bad design.

Comment: [bitmask_attributes](https://github.com/joelmoss/bitmask_attributes) is another gem that makes creating and managing roles easy.

Answer (score 0):

There are basically three kinds of role systems:

### 1. Dirt simple using an enum:

```
class User
  enum role: [:a, :b, :c]
end
```

This works great for the simplest possible case where a user can only have one role.

### 2. Three tables:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :user_roles
  has_many :roles, through: :user_roles

  has_role?(name, resource = nil)
    roles.exist?({ name: name, resource: resource }.compact)
  end
end

class Role < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :user_roles
  belongs_to :resource, polymorphic: true, optional: true
end
 
class UserRole < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :role
end
```

The key here is that `roles` is a separate normalized table. Storing the user ids directly on `roles` would lead to duplicating the role definitions over and over (think 1000's of rows with `name: "admin"`).

[Rolify](https://github.com/RolifyCommunity/rolify) is great if you want to spend your time better than reinventing the wheel. Combine this with an auth library like Pundit.

### 3. A hacky steaming pile:

There are tons of hacky attempts with array columns, non normalized tables etc. I even made one myself back in the day. Nothing to be ashamed of but authorization is one area where you should be humble enough to realize that many eyes are better than one.

Comment: The specific problems of your attempt is that you are jamming everything into a single table/model that will end up encompassing all the authorization logic for your application. In the end you'll have an endless number of enums with an endless number of options. Add to that that it actually takes attributes for a user.

Comment: Thank you. I'll try [Strongbolt gem](https://github.com/605data/strongbolt) as it allows to store roles and permissions in database + it seems to have solid Model level authorization.